# WPF Canvas Panning and Zoom

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I've created an application that can read an XML file and display the rail network specified within a WPF Canvas.

[image]

I've been struggling for a while (months) to get the following functionality working and looking for any clue on how to proceed:

- Zoom using mousewheel (zooming in makes the icons and tracks bigger whilst zooming out can let me see all the network).
- Panning - Using the middle mouse button to drag the view screen.

I ended up having to disable the mouse wheel as it just moved the scrollviewer. In order for me to scroll currently, I have to use the scrollbar arrows.

Usually I would upload code samples but I've also uploaded everything to GitHub with everything needed in case you need to dive into the code or compile.

https://github.com/Legolash2o/NMViewer

**XAML**

```
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="svCanvas" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  MouseMove="CCanvas_OnMouseMove" PreviewMouseWheel="SvCanvas_OnPreviewMouseWheel" MouseWheel="SvCanvas_OnPreviewMouseWheel" MouseDown="SvCanvas_OnMouseDown">
            <Canvas x:Name="cMain" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="36000" Height="58000"  >
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="st"/>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>              
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

**C#**

```
 private void SvCanvas_OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void SvCanvas_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            st.ScaleX = 1;
            st.ScaleY = 1;
        }
    }

    private void CCanvas_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (drawing)
            return;

        lblBar.Content =
            $"H[{svCanvas.HorizontalOffset}, V{svCanvas.VerticalOffset}] Mouse: {Mouse.GetPosition(cMain)}";
    }
```